# java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError while loading DB2 JDBC driver

Tags: java, macos, jdbc, db2

I try to use jboss-seam with a db2 database, the following error occurs

```
com.ibm.db2.jcc.a.SqlException: [jcc][10389][12245][3.52.95] while loading the native 
library   db2jcct2, java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no db2jcct2 in java.library.path  
an error occurred ERRORCODE=-4472, SQLSTATE=null
```

I tried setting `-Djava.library.path=/opt/IBM/db2/V9.5/lib64` as well as

```
-Djava.library.path=/opt/IBM/db2/V9.5/lib32
```

Both paths include `libdb2jcct2.so`

I also tried to set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` with no effect.

OS is MacOs

EDIT
I also tried to use a JDBC4 driver , db2jcc4.jar since jdbc4 drivers shouldn't rely on native libs.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The IBM Data Server Driver for JDBC and SQLJ includes both Type 2 and Type 4 JDBC drivers.  Please check the following:

1)  Make sure the driver is in your classpath: db2jcc.jar.  Alternatively you can use the JDBC4 driver (db2jcc4.jar), but don't put both in the classpath.

2)  Make sure that you're specifying the JCC driver (`com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver`) in your app configuration.

3)  Use a Type-4 URL like `jdbc:db2://server:port/database`.  If you specify a Type-2 URL like `jdbc:db2:database` then the driver will start looking for native libraries.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried setting `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` too? Might be worth a shot.

Comment: +1 DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH is used on MacOs instead of LD_LIBRARY_PATH

Answer (score 2):

From the path, this looks a linux /unix platform. Try running [strace/truss](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strace) to see which directories are getting opened for library.

Comment: +1 good hint, for the records the tool on a mac is called dtrace. dtrace -n 'syscall::open*:entry { printf("%s %s",execname,copyinstr(arg0)); }'

Answer (score 2):

Append a "driverType=4;" to your URL.

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't find a clear example anywhere, so I'm pasting my solution here.  What fixed me up was adding a xa-datasource-property of "DriverType" value "4".

```
            <xa-datasource jndi-name="java:/DB2DataSource" pool-name="DB2DataSource" enabled="true" use-ccm="true">
                <xa-datasource-property name="ServerName">
                    my.server.com
                </xa-datasource-property>
                <xa-datasource-property name="DatabaseName">
                    SAMBLEDB
                </xa-datasource-property>
                <xa-datasource-property name="PortNumber">
                    50000
                </xa-datasource-property>
                <xa-datasource-property name="DriverType">
                    4
                </xa-datasource-property>
                <driver>ibmdb2</driver>
                <xa-pool>
                    <is-same-rm-override>false</is-same-rm-override>
                </xa-pool>
                <security>
                    <user-name>username</user-name>
                    <password>supersecret</password>
                </security>
                <recovery>
                    <recover-plugin class-name="org.jboss.jca.core.recovery.ConfigurableRecoveryPlugin"/>
                </recovery>
                <validation>
                    <valid-connection-checker class-name="org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.extensions.db2.DB2ValidConnectionChecker"/>
                    <background-validation>true</background-validation>
                    <stale-connection-checker class-name="org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.extensions.db2.DB2StaleConnectionChecker"/>
                    <exception-sorter class-name="org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.extensions.db2.DB2ExceptionSorter"/>
                </validation>

            </xa-datasource>
```

Answer (score -1):

If the `java.library.path` (assigned using LD_LIBRARY_PATH env. variable) is wrong you should actually get something like: "failure in load of t2 native library".

You can check the `java.library.path` to se if the path is included like this.

`System.out.println(System.getProperty("java.library.path"));`

Could you be missing another jar like `db2jcc_license_cu.jar`

Maybe post your classpath. You can get it by reading the property `java.class.path` from the coide (like above).